# How to solve the special ode with general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The ode equation is $y'^2+2xy'+2y=0$ without initial value.

Is there a general solution？

If $y(0)=0$, what about the solution?

Answer (score 2):

$$y'^2+2xy'+2y=0$$
$$\frac 12y'^2+xy'=-y$$
$$y=-\frac 12y'^2-xy'$$
It's [D'Alembert differential equation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/d%27Alembert) 
$$y=xf(y')+g(y')$$
$$y=-\frac 12y'^2-xy'$$
$$2y'=-y'y''-xy''$$
$$2y'=\dfrac {dy'}{dx}\left (-y'-x \right)$$
$$2y'\dfrac {dx}{dy'}+x=-y'$$
It's linear.

Comment: I up voted, but is there a tiny mistake? I think your 6th line should be $2y'=-y'y''-xy''$

Comment: Oh thats a typo thank you @MasterYoda

Comment: very nice! is there some better reference on this kind of equation? I only found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation

Comment: Yes thats a good reference. I think that any textbook on differential equation will treat D'alembert's equation. @mrcntn

Answer (score 1):

The general solution can be written in implicit form as
$$ {\frac {c}{\sqrt {-x\pm\sqrt {{x}^{2}-2\,y \left( x \right) }}}}+2\,x
\pm \sqrt {{x}^{2}-2\,y \left( x \right) }=0
 $$

Of course $y(x)=0$ is a solution with $y(0)=0$.  However, it is not unique (the hypotheses of the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem are not satisfied): another solution is $y(x)= - 3 x^2/2$ (obtained from the general solution with $c=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha is able to solve it exactly,

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5B+%28f%27%5Bx%5D%29%5E2+%2B+2+x+f%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+2+f%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C+f%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D&wal=header

but I am not sure you will find this solution useful. It is extremely complex (the ODE is non-linear!).